# Android shared preferences conditional activity switching

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, switching

I have an Android app which I use to register users on my web site. My first task is to register a user if my shared preferences file shows there is no registered user information.

If my app has a registered user, I provide the following code to simply and automatically switch to a "homepage" activity:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin);
        
        if( USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERMAIL, "")  == null && USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERID, "") == null && USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERNAME, "") == null){
            //setContentView(R.layout.signin);
            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "testing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Intent intent   =   new Intent(SignIn.this, Confirmed.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
... other code
```

So, from my default activity, signin.java, the app will either switch to the Confirmed activity or stay on and display the signin activity.

My problem is, when the system works and I get switched to the the Confirmed activity, I provide a logout onclick listener which is below:

```
 signout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //USERPREFERENCES.cl
                Toast.makeText(Confirmed.this, "signout responding!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                USERPREFERENCES.edit().clear().commit();
            }
        });
```

It responds and clears all my shared preferences variables. But, when I use my menu to manually switch to the sign-in activity, I still get switched back to the Confirmed activity.

This happens even though I can confirm the variables are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hardly ever will be true:

```
USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERMAIL, "")  == null
```

What if you use this instead?

```
if( USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERMAIL, null)  == null && USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERID, null) == null && USERPREFERENCES.getString(USERPREFERENCES_USERNAME, null) == null){
    //setContentView(R.layout.signin); TRY TO AVOID DOING THIS THING!!!!!
    Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "testing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else...
```

Also, as a recommendation... instead of being switching between activities... what if you create just a Signing.java activity and put a `ViewFlipper` in its layout. That way your app will be not only faster but also easier to maintain.

Comment: Huh, good catch on the "" != null. I wonder how it was working for him originally.

Comment: Thank you you both - particularly Christian. Your input helped me see where I was going badly wrong. And, I will look into the ViewFlipper too
Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is Because When you will switch back to LoginActivity, this will be resumed instead of being created , Means your Login code which you written inOnCreate will not be called because Dthis time Overrider OnResume has been called , not onCreate .

So either write this code again in onResume or call finish() before moving to second activity , so that next time it will call onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate back to the first activity, the `onCreate` is not called again (unless the activity was destroyed for lack of resources). Move the authentication code in `onResume`.

Comment: Thank you. A bit more life-cycle know-how required on my part. Thanks again